# FTP Apache Commons stalls at retrieveFile

Tags: java, apache, ftp, apache-commons

I have a little test program i created to use later on and it simply connects to a server and retrieves a file if looks like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.SocketException;


public class Test {
     private final String pass = [I removed this password];
        FTPClient ftp;
        File file = new File("download.txt");
        private int reply;
        FileOutputStream dfile;

        public void ftp() {
            try {
                ftp = new FTPClient();
                ftp.connect("ftp.bevilacqua.me");
                ftp.login([i removed this username] ,[I removed this password]);

                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

                if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                    System.out.println("Connected Success");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
                    ftp.disconnect();
                }

                if(file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("File already exists");
                } 

                dfile = new FileOutputStream(file);


                ftp.retrieveFile("untitled.txt", dfile); //Untitled does exist in directory '/'
                System.out.println("Success... maybe");


            } catch(SocketException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test main = new Test();
        main.ftp();
        try {
            main.ftp.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The program prints Connected Success and File already exists so it has to be the retrieve file. The program doesn't crash and no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I would try these first:

1) Passive Mode (this instructs the client to make all the connections, not the server) 
 ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

2) A Data Timeout (this should stop indefinite hangs, but if you set the value too short, then you could bail out early slow connection) its difficult to simulate and test - just try it.
 ftp.setDataTimeout(10000);//ten seconds

Ultimately theres a way of passing a protocolMessageHandler to the underlying socket so you should be able to log the chatter between client and server. I've never done this though, but I imagine it has a high chance of revealing the real problem.